# What's wrong with my WSDL?

Tags: wsdl, apache-axis, wsdl2java, xmlbeans

Spent all day trying to generate an xmlbeans binding using wsdl2java (Axis2 1.5.4)  Completely befuddled.  Here's my command line:

```
wsdl2java.bat -uri http://localhost:3000/api/wsdl -d xmlbeans -a -or -o build/client
```

Here's the WSDL:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wsdl2:description xmlns:wsdlx="http://www.w3.org/ns/wsdl-extensions" xmlns:whttp="http://www.w3.org/ns/wsdl/http" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:wsdl2="http://www.w3.org/ns/wsdl" xmlns:tns="http://localhost:3000/api/wsdl" targetNamespace="http://localhost:3000/api/wsdl">
  <wsdl2:documentation>
  </wsdl2:documentation>
  <wsdl2:types>
    <xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="unqualified" targetNamespace="http://localhost:3000/api/wsdl">
      <xs:element type="tns:loginType" name="login">
    <xs:annotation>
      <xs:documentation>
      </xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element type="tns:idType" name="id">
    <xs:annotation>
      <xs:documentation>
      </xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:complexType name="loginType">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="email"/>
      <xs:element type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="password"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:complexType name="idType">
    <xs:attribute type="xs:int" name="id"/>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
  </wsdl2:types>
  <wsdl2:interface name="AtlasServiceInterface">
    <wsdl2:operation style="http://www.w3.org/ns/wsdl/style/iri" name="login" pattern="http://www.w3.org/ns/wsdl/in-out">
      <wsdl2:documentation>
      </wsdl2:documentation>
      <wsdl2:input messageLabel="In" element="tns:login"/>
      <wsdl2:output messageLabel="Out" element="tns:id"/>
    </wsdl2:operation>
  </wsdl2:interface>
  <wsdl2:binding type="https://www.w3.org/ns/wsdl/http" interface="tns:AtlasServiceInterface" name="AtlasServiceHTTPBinding">
    <wsdl2:documentation>
    </wsdl2:documentation>
    <wsdl2:operation ref="tns:login" whttp:method="POST" whttp:location="login"/>
  </wsdl2:binding>
  <wsdl2:service interface="tns:AtlasServiceInterface" name="AtlasService">
    <wsdl2:endpoint binding="tns:AtlasServiceHTTPBinding" name="AtlasServiceHTTPEndpoint" address="http://localhost:3000/api/"/>
  </wsdl2:service>
</wsdl2:description>
```

I know this is a HTTP binding... if it's not supported, an error message would be nice.

**UPDATE0**
I should add that wsdl2java completes, and I get some java classes.  AtlasServiceStub is there, but when I try to use it, there is no method for my login operation.

Comment: Same problem, missing some required/must methods when I generate stubs using xmlbeans options for my WSDL. Have you found any solution yet? Please share.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Started to work once I added the following to the operation definition:

```
whttp:inputSerialization="application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably it's because you have "wsdl2" prefix and the wsdl2java converter doesn't understand it correctly? BTW The Eclipse WSDL Editor shows empty pane when I try to open your file.